# How to edit wordpress Pablo Gaudi theme container height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My second attempt at posting a question at stack overflow.

I'm trying to reduce the height of a top panel responsive banner for the wordpress theme Pablo Gaudi. I've taken a screenshot to illustrate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3QBe.jpg

The challenge I'm facing is I could only seem to increase the height size but not reduce it. I've tested by editing height from 0 to 10px (under the .content_container:after) in the screenshot.

The website is hakataai.com and am still making lots of tweaks around this to make it more user friendly.

Hope someone can help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a css for it.

```
background-size:cover;
```

**Here is the screenshot**[image]

In case of any query feel free to contact;

Thanks;

Comment: Thanks! 
I managed to find it, it was in the styles.css file outside the css folder. I was focusing too much within the css folder but thanks!

Comment: @user9158446 My pleasure. :)